# Nullpointer exception in LinkedList while using for-each loop

Tags: java

I came across very odd Java behaviour, and I don't know if it is a bug, or
am I missing something.

The code simply goes through the stateStack (LinkedList) list and destroy all the states.

```
public void clearStates()
{
    LogFactory.getLog(StateController.class.getName())
      .info( "Clearing states. #ofstates="+stateStack.size());
    for (State state : stateStack)  // Line 132 (see exception)
    {
        state.destroy();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The following exception was trowed:

```
INFO  controllers.StateController : Clearing states. #ofstates=1
java.lang.NullPointerException\
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:891)
    at *.controllers.StateController.clearStates(StateController.java:132)
    // ... //
```

This code usually works without a problem and has been in the production for more than a year.

Is it possible that this is Java bug?

/*** Update ***/

destroy() call does not modify stateStack. If it would I guess Java would
throw ConcurrentModificationException.

stateStack was populated with 1 state, which overrides destroy, but only does
local modifications. The super implementation than prints additional log ("Destroying state..."), which was not in the log file, so I guess the exception was thrown at
the beginning of iteration.

```
public void destroy()
{
    destroyed = true;
    LogFactory.getLog(State.class.getName()).info( "Destorying state : "+getClass().getName());
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_DESTROYED, null, this);
}
```

Comment: Where is line `:132`? Maybe `state` in your list is `null`?

Comment: How and where do you get the stateStack?

Comment: What is the implementation of `state.destroy()`. What does it do? Also, how is `stateStack` populated?

Comment: Is it possible that the list is being changed by another thread during the iteration?

Comment: It does seem to be a java bug, because it happens on `iterator.next()`, rather than `state.destroy()`. You could [file a bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/)

Comment: @Manuel even if the item in the list is `null`,  the list must return `null` and not throw an internal exception. It looks like concurrent modification.

Comment: What is the java version?

Comment: @tbodt I very much doubt that it is a bug in the JDK...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The piece of code below generates the same exception almost every time I run it - the idea is to modify the list while iterating from another thread. With (un-)lucky timing, the modification happens after `checkForComodification` but before `next = next.next;` in the `ListItr#next` method, causing a NPE.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:891)
>       at javaapplication4.Test1.main(Test1.java:74)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 100000;
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        Runnable remove = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    int i = rand.nextInt(SIZE);
                    list.remove(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        break;
                    }
                    list.add(i);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(remove);
        t.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                for (Integer j: list) {
                    ///whatever
                }
            } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the internal implementation of `LinkedList.ListItr.next()`:

```
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    lastReturned = next;
    next = next.next;   // your stacktrace says the NullPointerException happens here
    nextIndex++;
    return lastReturned.item;
}
```

The `NullPointerException` happens because the internal variable `next` is `null`; however, it seems that `hasNext()` is validating that there is a next element.

It seems to me that:

- you have more than one thread modifying your list, OR
- you are modifying your list in the implementation of `destroy()` while iterating over the list.

If you update your answer with your implementation of `destroy()` as sugested by @mthmulders, I either update, correct or delete my answer.